# error in combobox using SEAM 2.1.2 and JBOSS 4.2.3GA

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam, facelets

I'm trying to create a combobox on a sean project and the sean tags are not recognizing my session bean method, but if i display the list in a simple table everything is ok.

### My session bean PaisSB.java:

package br.com.logical.prepark.session;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Factory;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Logger;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Out;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.datamodel.DataModel;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.datamodel.DataModelSelection;
import org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesMessages;
import org.jboss.seam.log.Log;

import br.com.logical.prepark.entity.bean.Pais;

@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
@Name("paisSB")
public class PaisSB{

@DataModel
   private List lstPais;

@In (required=false)
   @Out (required=false)
   @DataModelSelection
   private Pais pais;

@In
   private EntityManager entityManager;

@Logger
   private static Log log;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Factory("lstPais")
   public String listar(){

```
  lstPais = (List<Pais>) entityManager.createQuery("select pais from Pais pais").getResultList();

  if (lstPais.size()==0 ){
     return "/pages/parametro/consultarParametro.xhtml";
  }else{
     FacesMessages.instance().add("Pais #{pais.nome} teste");
     return null;
  }
```

}

}

### My entitybean Pais.java:

package br.com.logical.prepark.entity.bean;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;

@Name("pais")
@Table(name="pais")
@Entity
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
public class Pais implements java.io.Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private int id;

@NotNull @Length(min=5, max=45)
@Column(name="NM_PAIS")
private String nome;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="pais")
private List<Parametro> lstParametro;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public List getLstParametro() {
    return lstParametro;
}

public void setLstParametro(List<Parametro> lstParametro) {
    this.lstParametro = lstParametro;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Pais other = (Pais) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

### tags inpage parametros.xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{parametro.pais}" required="true">                      
<s:selectItems value="#{paisSB.listar}" var="pais" label="#{pais.nome}" noSelectionLabel="Please Select..."/>
<s:convertEntity />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

### stacktrace

javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/parametro/consultarParametro.xhtml @30,119 value="#{paisSB.listar}": Property 'listar' not found on type br.com.logical.prepark.session.PaisSB_$$_javassist_seam_2
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.getSelectItems(RenderKitUtils.java:296)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:801)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:280)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:242)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:126)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:282)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:262)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:220)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:215)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:121)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:390)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:517)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/parametro/consultarParametro.xhtml @30,119 value="#{paisSB.listar}": Property 'listar' not found on type br.com.logical.prepark.session.PaisSB_$$_javassist_seam_2
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:141)
    ... 68 more

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bean PaisSB you declare lstPais, and not listar, so there is no listar in PaisSb, which is what the error message says.

You either need to rename lstPais to listar, or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you Jim, 

the problem was resolved but i need to create the getters and setters to for variable lstPais. I thought you could call any method to bind a session variable, but apparentely if you have a List A, the method to bind must be a getter of A as a simple POJO is that correct ?

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Factory("lstPais")
   public List<Pais> getLstPais() {
  
  lstPais = (List<Pais>) entityManager.createQuery("from Pais").getResultList();
  return lstPais;
 }

Comment: Yes anything you bind must follow the java bean spec.